# Bash: How to search for a specific phrase in all files named output.log across all sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find, command-line-interface

I'm struggling to figure out how this can be done, and searching isn't turning up much.. I have a feeling I will need to make a script.

Let's say I have a directory named 'Log outputs'. Inside of 'Log outputs' I have a folder for 2016, 2015, 2014.. etc. Inside each of these I have January, February, March.. And then finally inside each of these folders there will be a filed named output.log.

How can I run a command in the 'Log outputs' directory to scan all sub directories to look for a file named 'output.log', and then search for a specific phrase in this log file. I do not need it to search through any other files outside of output.log, and the directories can be organised X sub-directories deep.

Can't figure this one out despite playing around for quite a while..

Answer (score 3):

```
find 'Log outputs' -name 'output.log' -exec grep 'searchkey' {} \;
```

If you need to see the name of the file & line number, add `-Hn` to the grep command.

Comment: Nicely done; I suggest replacing `\;` with `+` for efficiency (you'll typically only get a _single_ invocation of `grep`. The logic is then reversed: `-h` is then needed to suppress the file prefix).

Comment: @mklement0:  Nice.  I've learned a lot today just from your comments.

Comment: That is fantastic, thanks. Seems to be very efficient and completes quickly. One thing I am not sure of: What is the purpose of \; vs + as mklement0 mentioned?